# Alternativas ao beforeunload event listener no FF

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Estou a trabalhar num website e JavaScript tem um papel importante no front-end, estava a usar o evento `beforeunload` para fazer sempre uma verificação se o utilizador editou algo na página, para avisa-lo sobre possíveis perdas de informação.

Acontece que este evento não é compatível com o firefox. Que alternativa posso usar para fazer essa verificação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [**`onbeforeunload`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) deve funcionar.

Exemplo de código - compatível com IE >= 7 também

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';

myEvent(chkevent, function(e) {
    fazerAlgumaCoisa();
});
```

---

Solução testada no Firefox Nightly 53.0a1

Comment: Funciona muito bem! Já estava a ficar desesperado porque pensei que não dava para fazer o que eu queria, mas estava enganado. Obrigado

Comment: Bom poder ajudar =D